# How to reduce the number of suggestions an input offers by matching the word?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an `input`, where the result has to autocomplete and there should not be more than 4 suggestions.

I did until now everything mentioned above. But, the problem  is, when I type a word, it’s repeating the same word  4 times.

What I want is, by matching the word, it reduces the number of suggestions.

In this pic I am searching for "paypal", by matching the word, it has to show fewer suggestions.

[image: This is my input]

Any solution please.

```
$('#word').autocomplete({
    source : function(req, res) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/AutoCompleteWords/AutoCompleteWordsServle",
            dataType: "json",
            data: req,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, req.term);
                res(results.slice(0, 4));


            }
        });
    },

    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#word').val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to check your network response to see if the same option is being returned multiple times.  If it is, this is a backend issue and not a javascript issue.

Comment: This is most likely a Server-Side issue. I suspect you're better off updating your DB Query and limiting the result to 4 there. Also you need to check your return payload to see what response you're getting. What do you see in Console?

Answer (score 0):

I would change your Autocomplete like the following.

```
$('#word').autocomplete({
  source : "http://localhost:8080/AutoCompleteWords/AutoCompleteWordsServle"
  minLength: 3
});
```

> When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must support CORS). The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a `term` field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is set to `"http://example.com"` and the user types `foo`, a GET request would be made to `http://example.com?term=foo`. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.

On the Server side, you would then extract `term` from the Request and perform your query like so:

```
SELECT words FROM TableName WHERE LIKE '$term%' LIMIT 4;
```

This will ensure that a term like `"pay"` will get only 4 results and will return a list of words like `"payment", "paypal", "pays"` etc depending on your data set.

The `minLength` will ensure that you are not sending `"p"` or `"pa"` to the script. Since this would generate a very large result set in the first place. So as long as we send at least 3 characters, we should narrow the results a good amount.

Answer (score 0):

## QUICK FIX:

Mention the limit (3) in your SQL.